# image button error: System.ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument

Tags: asp.net

In the grid view I have uploaded files with image icon. For having image icon in the grid view and getting type of uploaded file in the row (command Argument), I have used image button, it shows the image icon but when I click on the image button, I have error" System.ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument"
If I could use image control instead of image button for me was better, but I do not know how to get extension file type from row.
Also if we could disable link image button in this case, was no problem.

**Desin of database for tblfile is like below:**

```
Fileid(int)
Docid(int)
TransId(int)
Content type varchar(75)
Data varbinary(max)
Extention varchar(50)
```

**Cs:**

```
protected void GridViewEfile_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridViewEfile.Rows)                   //loop each row
    {
        ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)gvr.FindControl("ib1");    //find imagebutton

        string exten = ib.CommandArgument;;      //get index of '.'
        if (exten == ".pdf")
            ib.ImageUrl = @"~/Images/iconpdf.gif";                      //set image for imagebutton in each row

        else if (exten == ".docx")

            ib.ImageUrl = @"~/Images/icondoc.gif";

    }
}

protected void ib1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{

       _DataContext = new EDMSDataContext();
       //you can get your command argument values as follows
       string FileId = e.CommandName.ToString();
       int _FileId = Convert.ToInt32(FileId);
       tblFile Efile = (from ef in _DataContext.tblFiles
                        where ef.FileId == _FileId
                        select ef).Single();
       if (Efile != null)
       {

           download(Efile);

       }
   }
```

**.aspx:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewEfile" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
    OnDataBound="GridViewEfile_DataBound" ForeColor="Black" DataKeyNames="FileID"
    GridLines="None" ShowHeader="False">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="Yellow" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="ib1" OnCommand="ib1_Command" CommandName='<%#Eval("FileID")%>'
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Exten") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnCommand="LinkButton1_Command" CommandName="Download"
                CommandArgument='<%#Eval("FileID")%>'><%#Eval("FileName")%></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ContentType" />
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Red" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
   <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
   <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
</asp:GridView>
```